# How to manually trigger JsonSerialization Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an application where in the startup, I register NewtonSoft with error logging on serialization. When I check my application log, I can see there are error logs but I am having trouble pin pointing or recreating the error.

The error: `Failed during serialization: MoveNextAction.Method.ReturnTypeCustomAttributes`

Startup.cs

```
.AddControllersAsServices().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.UseMemberCasing();
    options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    options.AllowInputFormatterExceptionMessages = true;
    options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.None;
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
    {
        NamingStrategy = null
    };
    options.SerializerSettings.Error = (sender, args) =>
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Failed during serialization: {args.ErrorContext.Path}", args.ErrorContext.Error);
        args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
    };
})
```

I did a search in my application for **serial**

- A couple classes have the [Serializable] attribute

I also use DeserializeObject

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonValue);
```

I tried and set jsonValue to null but unfortunately that did not trigger SerializerSettings.Error.

Any tips or suggestions on generating a SerializerSettings error or debugging would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does `_logger.LogError($"Failed during serialization: {args.ErrorContext.Path}", args.ErrorContext.Error)` actually print? can you add that to your question? Basically, `args.ErrorContext.Error` should show you the type that was being serialized and failed (at the bottom of the stack trace).

Comment: Hi there, I did add it up top. Failed during serialization: MoveNextAction.Method.ReturnTypeCustomAttributes

Comment: That's the value of `args.ErrorContext.Path`. But what's the value of `args.ErrorContext.Error`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by passing an invalid JSON request body compared with the model class specified in the controller arguments.

Define a model class with an int field, then send an HTTP request where there is a string value in the JSON for that field.

This would come through to the controller as the default value, and in your case the Error handler should be executed as well.

Here is a working example:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public class MyRequest
    {
        public int MyField { get; set; }
    }

    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Test([FromBody] MyRequest myRequest)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

If you POST to /Home/Test the value

```
{
    "MyField": "test"
}
```

then your error handler will be invoked, and the value of `args.ErrorContext.Path` will be `MyField`

Although, the value of `args.ErrorContext.Error` will be  `Message = "Could not convert string to integer: test. Path 'MyField', line 2, position 18."` I think I would need a much deeper understanding of your code to reproduce the error exactly, but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you add `.AddControllersAsServices().AddNewtonsoftJson...` it just triggers during input and output of your actions (actually in model binding and return action result).

So if you want trigger json serialize error in all your project you must set `JsonSerializerSettings` explicitly in your startup like this:

```
var defaultJsonConvertSetting = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                Formatting = Formatting.None,
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
                ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver {NamingStrategy = null},
               
                Error = (sender, args) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"**********************Failed during serialization: {args.ErrorContext.Path}");
                    args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
                }
                // other settings
            };

            JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => defaultJsonConvertSetting;

                .AddControllersAsServices().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                options.UseMemberCasing();
                options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                options.AllowInputFormatterExceptionMessages = true;
                options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.None;
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
                {
                    NamingStrategy = null
                };
                options.SerializerSettings.Error = (sender, args) =>
                {
                    _logger.LogError($"Failed during serialization: {args.ErrorContext.Path}", args.ErrorContext.Error);
                    args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
                };
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for the informative response, may I ask how would I trigger the error?

Comment: @Master I said in the answer! You should define ``JsonSerializerSettings`` in your startup. tested and worked fine.

Comment: Hi, I see within default setting, there's extra logic for error. But that doesn't quite state how to trigger an actual error. In other words, how can I get the console to write that line? That was the main issue of my post.